# React Native Orientation does not listening Current System Auto Rotate Status

Tags: react-native, orientation, screen-orientation, autorotate

Im using `react-native-orientation` . I want to lock  initial login screen in portrait mode. so i have used  `Orientation.lockToPortrait()` in app.tsx ,and `Orientation.unlockAllOrientations()` in a screen's constructor that i want to enable rotation again.

But the problem is when Device/emulators system auto rotate Disabled from notification bar it still rotates.I want to rotate if Device/emulators system auto rotate enabled. otherwise not.

So is there any way to listen system/device rotation status?
or any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

react-native-orientation the package dont have such feature react-native-orientation-locker solved my problem.